# EXCEL Remove entries based on date

Tags: excel, date, filter, vba

Hi I currently have a spreadsheet where I have a macro that deletes entries that are not meeting my criteria

```
Sub AutoFilter_in_Excel()

Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="2"
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="Bob"
End Sub
```

How could I add the ability to also remove entries that do not have a date within say the last four days as well as my existing macro above?

The dates are formatted like this

07/06/2014

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VBA function of `NOW()` to get the current date and for every whole number you subtract, you get 1 day before, so, for example, `NOW() - 4` would equal 4 days before today.

So, using this logic, your code could become:

```
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=??, Criteria1:=">=" & Now() - 4, _
                       Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Now()
```

Obviously, replace the `??` with the field you want to set that filter for.

There should be no need to worry about how the dates are formatted in your sheet either - So long as they are stored as dates in Excel and not as text, this filter should work.

Hope that does the trick!!